# CSS WebKit Overflow Hidden Border Radius Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of circles that when clicked animate a div (.active) from top to bottom that gets displayed within the original circle. In Firefox the animated divs are masked but in Safari and Chrome the animated div (.active) can be seen and don't mask themselves to the parent li.

I've seen a few other posts with this issue but not with animating.

Has anyone else had this issue or know of a solution?

```
HTML

<ul class="circles">
  <li class="image-1"><div class="active"><p>text text</p></div></li>
  <li class="image-2"><div class="active"><p>text text</p></div></li>
  <li class="image-3"><div class="active"><p>text text</p></div></li>                                                                          
</ul> 

CSS

ul.circles li{float:left; text-align: center; background-color:blue; height:186px; width:186px; border-radius:200px; border:10px solid white; overflow:hidden; display:block; position:relative;}
ul.circles li.image-1{background:url(image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;}         
ul.circles li .active{background: rgb(154, 189, 44); position:relative; width:186px; height:186px; top:190px; border-radius:200px;} 

JS

$('.circles li').toggle(function() {
    $(this).find('div').animate({opacity: 0.8, top:'0'}, 1000 )
},function() {
    $(this).find('div').animate({opacity: 0.7, top:'190px'}, 1000 );
});
```

Comment: Looks the same in chrome and firefox for me, http://jsfiddle.net/PrZZc/

Comment: Not for me in Chrome I can still see the .active div at the bottom of the circle so it's still not being masked.

Comment: Know bug in WebKit unfortunately ( https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72619 ). There are some suggestions in the bug comments that might help?

Answer (score 0):

Maby this can help,

if the circle doesn't have to contain links that are clickable you could place an transparent image on top, i used an image i found on google so i had to change the width and height.

http://jsfiddle.net/PrZZc/22/

the black borders came with the image so you have to create your own